# Unir duas consultas no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, tenho duas consultas da mesma tabela, porém não estou conseguindo uni-las paralelamente, já tentei usar o `UNION`, mas não funcionou, há algum modo de fazer isso? Ou então criar uma coluna com a diferença acumulada (Backlog) entre os totais das duas tabelas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(created) AS 'MES'
   ,YEAR(created) AS 'ANO'
   ,COUNT(Number) AS 'TOTAL'
FROM [ServiceNow VR01].[dbo].[incident]
    WHERE created > '2013-01-01' 
    GROUP BY YEAR(created), MONTH(created) 
    ORDER BY ANO, MES

SELECT 
    MONTH([Closed AT]) AS 'MES'
   ,YEAR([Closed AT]) AS 'ANO'
   ,COUNT(Number) AS 'TOTAL' 
FROM [ServiceNow VR01].[dbo].[incident] 
    WHERE [Closed AT] > '2013-01-01' 
    GROUP BY HONTH([Closed AT]), YEAR([Closed AT]) 
    ORDER BY ANO, MES
```

Tipo assim:

```
 Total C  Total F   Balance    Backlog
 1420   - 424    =  996        996
 18433  - 9480   =  8953       9949
 26500  - 30137  = -3637       6312
```

Obs: Estou usando o SQL Server 2012 e as duas tabelas tem a mesma quantidade de linhas.

Comment: Fala Thiago, isto te ajudaria? [Alternative to UNION clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535872/alternative-to-union-clause)

Comment: Olá viva, de forma a poder ajudar-te, explica melhor o que queres, na query que apresentas o output será MES, ANO e TOTAL, e a tabela de resultado queres algo 'Tipo assim:' Total C, Total F, Balance e Backlog, adicionalmente se colocares na plataforma sqlfiddle um exemplo da tua tabela real com alguns dos dados juntamente com a tua query base, ajuda bastante e será mais fácil seres ajudado...  plataforma: (http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: Pelo que consegui entender me parece que uma INNER JOIN com mês e ano atenderia ao que deseja. Se nem sempre ocorrem em ambas as tabelas talvez uma OUTER JOIN seja melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi um join usando os dois sql como tabelas virtuais , de resto é manipular os campos alinhados.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
( SELECT MONTH(created) AS 'MES' ,
 YEAR(created) AS 'ANO' ,
 COUNT(Number) AS 'TOTAL' 
 FROM [ServiceNow VR01].[dbo].[incident] 
 WHERE created > '2013-01-01' 
 GROUP BY YEAR(created), 
 MONTH(created)) TC,
 (SELECT MONTH([Closed AT]) AS 'MES' ,
  YEAR([Closed AT]) AS 'ANO' ,
  COUNT(Number) AS 'TOTAL' 
  FROM [ServiceNow VR01].[dbo].[incident] 
  WHERE [Closed AT] > '2013-01-01' 
  GROUP BY HONTH([Closed AT]), 
  YEAR([Closed AT])) TS
WHERE TC.ANO = TS.ANO
AND TC.MES = TS.MES
ORDER BY TC.ANO,TC.MES
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu perfeitamente.